# 3 Notifications because of old comments

Tags: bug, android-app

Until now I got <s>two</s> three (updated while filling the bug) notifications to my android device with more than 12 hours comments.

Please check it out as it's very disturbing.

Comment: Meta.SE bug report: [Stack Exchange Android app keeps replaying notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242988)

Comment: This should be resolved now, according to the devs over on Meta.SE.

Comment: I don't know but from all the apps installed on my phone,This one (StackExchange) gets crashed for the most number of times.(Even more than the one developed by me).